# Working with hex numbers in MySQL

Tags: mysql, hex

I have a stored procedure that needs to convert hexadecimal numbers to their decimal equivalent.  I've read the documentation for the UNHEX() function, but it is returning a binary value.  What I'm wanting to do is something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE foo( hex_val VARCHAR(10) )
BEGIN
    DECLARE dec_val INTEGER;

    SET dec_val = UNHEX( hex_val );

    -- Do something with the decimal value
    select dec_val;
END
```

What am I missing?  How can I convert the UNHEX()'d value to a unsigned integer?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the [`CONV()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_conv) function to convert between bases.

```
SET dec_val = CONV(hex_val, 16, 10);
```

Comment: Note that this will return the decimal as a *string*. If one wants to get the decimal as an integer, use:

cast(conv(hex_val, 16, 10) as unsigned)

Answer (score 8):

```
conv(hex_val, 16, 10)
```

Will convert a number of base 16 to base 10.  The UNHEX function does something completely different, it converts pairs of hex digits to characters.

Answer (score 7):

cast(conv(hex_val, 16, 10) as unsigned integer)
that should be solve the problem....